# Limits of sums in which the sum index is a function of the variable involved in the limit

Tags: limits

I came across this problem when trying to prove that the harmonic series diverges.  I need to prove that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} = 0
\end{equation}
Is he following methodology correct?

Firstly:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n}
= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} \frac{1}{N + n} 
\end{equation}
Consider
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{M} \frac{1}{N+m} \qquad \textrm{for some } M > 1, M \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{M} \frac{1}{N+m} 
= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N+1} + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N+2} + \space ... + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N+M} = 0 \space + 0 \space + \space ... + \space 0 = 0
\end{equation}
Hence is true that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{M} \frac{1}{N+m} 
= 0 \qquad \forall \space M : M > 1, M \in \mathbb{N} 
\end{equation}
Set $M = 2N + 1$
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=1}^{2N+1} \frac{1}{N+m} 
= 0 \qquad N \in \mathbb{N} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} = 0
\end{equation}

**Update:**

The problem was misspecified.  It was required to prove 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}
under the (false) assumption that the harmonic series has a finite limit $L$:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} = L
\end{equation}
In this case (relying on the fact that the sum is monotonically increasing):
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} = L
\Rightarrow \nexists \space N : \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} > L
\Rightarrow \nexists \space N : \sum_{n=1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} > L
\Rightarrow \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} \le L
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} +\sum_{n=N+1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} = L + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} \le L
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=N+1}^{3N+1} \frac{1}{n} = 0
\end{equation}

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The sum can be written as $H_{3N}-H_N$, where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). At the

same time, we also have $H_N\simeq\ln N$, and $\ln a-\ln b=\ln\dfrac ab$. Combining the three, we

conclude that the limit is $\ln3$. Your reasoning is incorrect, because, according to it, we

could also write $~1~=~\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\dfrac NN~=~\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac1N~=~\lim_{N\to\infty}\dfrac1N~+~\lim_{N\to\infty}\dfrac1N~+~\cdots~+$

$+~\lim_{N\to\infty}\dfrac1N~=~0~+~0~+~\cdots~+~0~=~0,~$ which is absurd.

Comment: Thanks very much Lucian.  Thought i didn't seem right.

Comment: Your last example is very illustrative - I see how it is similar to the indeterminate form infinity x zero, i.e. each term in the sum appears to be zero but there are infinitely many terms.